# Kioware - Logout of Go Skills when session ends or inactive

Tags: javascript, session, kiosk

I'm familiarising myself with Kioware and created a Portal page with buttons to different websites (Google, etc.).
Currently I have it set in the Session End Settings to when kiosk enters attract mode, the session clears nothing. For example if I was on Google, I search up something and the session goes to attract mode due inactivity, I move the mouse, brings me back to the main portal page and click on the button to Google it brings me back to my last session.
One of my buttons brings me to the login page of Go Skills (https://www.goskills.com/Login/) where I will I need put in my login details to gain access. What I want to do is when I'm in my Go Skills account and the session ends or goes to attract mode, it logs me out automatically, preventing the next Kiosk user from having access to my account on Go Skills.

I changed the Session End Settings to clear All User Data, including Cache and Cookie, but that effects all the sessions. I want it to just clear the Go SKills Session.
I checked the Automatic Action section of Kioware and have it set currently to if the URL contains https://www.goskills.com/. Execute the Javascript in the Current Browser (but have nothing filled in this section as I'm not too familiar with Javascript)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.